CORS Error when trying to access API Gateway Endpoint
I am trying to host an WebSite on S3. The site will trigger a lambda function and do some stuff.
I've managed to host the site and access it. Created the Lambda function. Created the API Gateway API, the method (POST) and the stage. However, even after enabling CORS i'm still having the same message (CORS error).
Here are my steps on API Gateway:

Create API - REST API
API Endpoint type: Regional
Create a Resource. Created a resource with the name "Upload". Selected the checkbox "CORS (Cross origin resource sharing)" [Create an OPTIONS method that allows all origins, all methods, and several common headers.]
Create a Method. Name Post
Enabled CORS for the POST method. Selected the method POST.
Updated my main.js with the endpoint URL

Access to fetch at 'https://ewe5juroi8.execute-api.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/ProdX/upload' from origin 'http://dataextractorbucket.s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
On the response header of the request, i've noticed the following:
"BadRequestException"
BUt the URL is in the correct format.
Check the image below:

Also, the response has the mentioned header.

